# How to display a collection in a list using display tag

Tags: struts2, jsp-tags

ok here is the scenario i have two pojo classes 
they are as follows

```
public class CodeSetting {

    private long codeSettingId;
    private String code;    
    private String codeDescription;
    private CodeType codeType;
    private Collection<Company> company = new ArrayList<Company>();

    }
public class Company
{
      private String comapny Name;  
}
```

now i want to display the codesetting using the display tag codesetting and company have many to many relationship ok.

so using display tag i can display the attributes of the codesetting by using a list of code setting object.

but the problem comes while displaying the company

as its also a collection it also needs to be iterated for each codesetting object but not possible using display tag tried using the iterator tag of struts2 but still no use

i want my display to be like this

code   codetype    company

M      marriage    abc,bca

if anyone came across the scenario and solved the problem do guide me through it would be very helpful .thanks in advance

Comment: what is `M merriage abc cba`?

Comment: its just the format of display i want

Comment: i can understand, `code codetype codeDescription` are your attributes, but you mean `M marriage abce ...` are the value of them? Which means `code=M, codetype=marriage, etc` ?

Comment: correct in this the company is a collection in a list of codesetting so for each codesetting the company should be iterated and displayed.so the situation becomes collection of code setting with each codesetting containing collection of company hope its a bit clear now

Comment: is your problem that, you wanna display a collection in one column? If yes, you can convert it to a string, then show it.

Comment: look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358422/how-to-show-nested-array-lists-using-display-tag-on-jsp

Answer (score 1):

finally got the answer need to use nested column in display tag only problem is while exporting as we are using nested sub list

```
<display:table id="parent"  name="codesettingList" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="5" pagesize="5" requestURI="/viewCodeSetting" >

                <display:column property="codeSettingId"  title="Code Setting ID" href="viewCodeSettingSelected" paramId="codeSettingId"/>
                <display:column property="code" title="Code"/>
                <display:column property="codeDescription" title="Code Description"/>
                <display:column property="codeType.codeType" title="Code Type" />


                <c:set var="nestedName" value="codesettingList[${parent_rowNum -1}].company" />

                <display:column title="Company">

                    <display:table  name="${nestedName}" id="child${parent_rowNum}" class="simple sublist">
                        <display:column property="companyName" ></display:column>
                    </display:table>


                </display:column> 

                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />

            </display:table>
```